# How to have one instance of Backing Bean per Browser tab?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

**My environment**: Java 7/JSF 2.1/PrimeFaces 6.1.

**My goal**: to have a certain page of my application instantiated many times, one for each browser tab, each one with a different context.

**My problem**: everytime I open a second browser tab requesting from the same url, but with different object id, the previous one is destroyed, so only one backing bean instance is kept alive.

**How do I know that**: In my backing bean I have one method annotated with `@PosConstruct` and other with `@PreDestroy`, so I can track the life cicle of the instances.

My backing bean is annotated as follows:

```
@ViewController
public class MyBackingBeanMB extends AbstractBackingBeanMB {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // many fields and methods
}
```

The `@ViewController` annotation is provided by the application framework I have to use. Such an annotation is declared as:

```
@Named
@Controller
@Stereotype
@ViewScoped // For me, this should do the trick, but...
@Target(value={TYPE})
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface ViewController {
}
```

## Update 1:

The `@Controller` annotation is also provided by the framework I use and is declared as:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Inherited
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Controller {
}
```

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

TIA.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `@Controller` annotation being one from JSF. And `@Viewscoped` is not for usage per tab. It is for scope per viewId, effectively resulting in the behaviour you see. You need a `@WindowScoped` from DeltaSpike or use a `@ConversationScoped`. There is a duplicate about this in Stackoverflow.

Comment: @BalusC: no, not using Spring, it's JSF with some additional services provided by a framework I have to use.

Comment: @Kukeltje: my mistake, I didn't provide the declaration of `@Controller`. Just did it. Sorry, but we have a bad history with `@ConversationScoped`, so it is not an option for us, since the medicine was much worse than the decease. Any other ideas?

Comment: @BalusC: alright, just to be absolutely sure that I understand my case here. You are telling me that in an absolutely standard JSF application I should be able to have one backing bean per browser tab with no problem if I use `@ViewScope`. Is that so?

Comment: Suggestion: WindowScoped... And if the  `@Controller` is in a custom framework, it is impossible to help further (at least for me since lots of things might happen in there)

Comment: Controller has an interceptorBinding... this substantiates my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

After some digging in the Internet I found Apache DeltaSpike, which provider a new kind of managed bean scope, `WindowScoped`.

Managed beans annotated with @WindowScoped` operate just like I wanted, providing me with the exact behaviour I needed and it is absolutely compatible with the framework I have to use.

Comment: Digging the internet? Why?  I commented two weeks ago about this scope...! if this works for you it is normally common practice (out ofcourtesy)  to ask the one suggesting it to create answer

Comment: Sorry, but I just reviewed your comments and found your suggestion, but you posted it after I decided to go further on the matter. It was not my intention to not give you the proper credit, but because the pressure I was suffering I did not have the time to get back here and see it. Please, post an answer and I will accept it as the correct one.